# how to embed videos from JW Player to another site?

Tags: javascript, html, video, embed

I have this news:

http://www.lanacion.com.ar/1923707-google-presento-su-guia-de-los-juegos-olimpicos-rio-2016

In the body, it has 2 videos embed with JW Player. It hasn't the video's url, only the video id. Is there any way to get the video url or embed the player?

If you see more slowly, in the page source there isn't any JS code related to the player either, even the url's JS library, only the CSS stylesheet..

I was trying to import JS library but i can't because i don't know the player ID..

In the docs, all the examples explain how to embed a video, but in my case i don't have the video url and it's just i looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the URL that is being played, watch the requests that are happening in the browser's Network monitor (part of developer tools). That will show you a URL.

It may not be much use though if the content is protected - they may do something like put a timestamp/IP hash on the URL or adopt some other scheme to avoid you linking directly to in.

In this case, for the first video, I was able to see the URL for the stream http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/oYFEN0e0.m3u8, and link to it in HTML (only tested in Safari, which I know handles HLS files):

```
<video controls autoplay src="http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/oYFEN0e0.m3u8"></video>
```

Comment: Hi, finally i resolved in another way. It happens that in each div that contains a video, it has a "video id". After 4 hours searching in Google, i found a post in forum that someone answered with a URL to search videos by id. The response is a JSON file, so the only thing i had to do was to convert the JSON to object in PHP and get the needed information, like a url video and width and height.

Thanks for your help!